# JQuery - Remember Image State

Tags: jquery, image, toggle, store, state

I have an image on my site that can be clicked. Once clicked jquery changes the image and runs an ajax query.

I'm not looking to have the image state remembered. It will either be ON or OFF.
I know I should be using cookies or local storage, but I need to make sure this works with some possibly old browsers, and I've no idea how to approach saving the state..

The code I'm using to toggle the image is :

```
jQuery(function(){
         $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
            } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
            }
            $(this).toggleClass("on");
        });
});
```

I've created a **[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CkDq/)** to show the toggling of the image and that does work, but can some one point me in the right direction for remembering the image state on a page reload or refresh.

Thanks

Comment: you have to store it on in a hidden field and on redirect post it and on next page load get it

Comment: well use localStorage, cookie based approach, other than this you can pass the params in your url like `yoururl?src=_on`.

Comment: Thanks - are you aware of any cookie based examples ?

Comment: by the way stop using `live` use `on` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**using localstorage:**

**jsfiddle:**
**http://jsfiddle.net/9CkDq/1/**

```
jQuery(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("class") =="on"){   
        $(".img-swap").attr("src",$(".img-swap").attr("src").replace("_off","_on")).addClass("on");
    }
    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            localStorage.setItem("class","on");
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("class","off");
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");            
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

**using cookies:**

**jsfiddle:**
**http://jsfiddle.net/9CkDq/9/**

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

jQuery(function(){
    if(getCookie("class")=="_on"){   
        $(".img-swap").attr("src",$(".img-swap").attr("src").replace("_off","_on")).addClass("on");
    }
    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            setCookie("class","_on");
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on",30);
        } else {
            setCookie("class","_off");
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off",30);            
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

you can use sessions to store the state for a particular session and db to save state for ever.

Comment: Thanks, they both seem perfect :)

Comment: Just a side though, could this be adapted to allow the remembering of multiple images states ? same image names but each <img> has a unique attrib called 'loc'. ?  Thanks

Comment: can you update your question or ask a new question. `loc` attribute, I didn't get that. you should upvote and accept if this helped

Comment: Thanks - I'll ask a new question.

Comment: New ticket opened : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135846/jquery-remember-multiple-image-states