# JQuery - Remember Multiple Image States

Tags: jquery, image, cookies, toggle, state

As a follow on to my question yesterday, **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105293/jquery-remember-image-state)**

I have multiple images on my site that can be clicked. Once clicked jquery changes the selected image and runs a specific ajax query.

I'm now looking to have the image states remembered. They will either be ON or OFF.

This is the jquery cookie code that was suggested on my previous question for doing this with ONE image:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

jQuery(function(){
    if(getCookie("class")=="_on"){   
        $(".img-swap").attr("src",$(".img-swap").attr("src").replace("_off","_on")).addClass("on");
    }
    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            setCookie("class","_on");
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
            setCookie("class","_off");
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");            
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

Now I will have multiple copies of the same image with in a table.

Each  will have a unique attribute **loc** assigned to it, the attributes name will be constant for all  tags but the value will be unique.

```
<img class="img-swap on" loc="54874000-54AF" title="" src="images/on.png">
<img class="img-swap on" loc="875900AD-C4E2" title="" src="images/on.png">
<img class="img-swap on" loc="845AC804-1A5F" title="" src="images/on.png">
```

Can anyone advise the best way to remember the state of each image on the page.

I'm thinking it may be possible to use the value of **loc** and set the cookie based on that, but I'm not sure how as I could have 50+ images.

Thanks for all advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSFIDDLE:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/9CkDq/8**/

**html:**

```
<img src="http://www.designchemical.com/lab/media/images/img_swap_off.png" loc="54874000-54AF" alt="" class="img-swap" /> 
<img src="http://www.designchemical.com/lab/media/images/img_swap_off.png" loc="875900AD-C4E2" alt="" class="img-swap" />
<img src="http://www.designchemical.com/lab/media/images/img_swap_off.png" loc="845AC804-1A5F" alt="" class="img-swap" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

jQuery(function(){
    $(".img-swap").each(function(){
        if(getCookie($(this).attr("loc"))=="on"){   
            $(this).attr("src",$(".img-swap").attr("src").replace("_off","_on")).addClass("on");
        }
    });

    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            setCookie($(this).attr("loc"),"on",30);
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
            setCookie($(this).attr("loc"),"off",30);
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");            
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry not had a chance to check this. Will do shortly :) Thanks